# Spotify webplayer account checker with Python Selenium automation

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, automation, spotify

I am new to coding and I am trying to write a www.open.spotify.com account checker for spotify web player with python and selenium.

I got python to login and log out with this code ; 
(reason for usage of xpath in some cases is because there are in those cases no id for elements in HTML)

...

## imports

```
    import time
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by 
    import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import 
    WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import 
    expected_conditions as ec
    import random
    from selenium import webdriver
    from 
    selenium.common.exceptions 
    import NoSuchElementException
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options 
    import Options
    import os
```

## code

```
while True:
  startTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
print('\n')
usernamelist =  'example@email.com'
passwordstr2 = 'password'


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()


browser.get('https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2F')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-username")))
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-password")))
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-button")))
k = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/label/span').click()


# log in chrome 1
username = browser.find_element_by_id('login-username')
choice_name = (random.choice(usernamelist))
username.send_keys(choice_name)
print(choice_name)


password = browser.find_element_by_id('login-password')
password.send_keys(passwordstr2)
time.sleep(5)


login_Button = browser.find_element_by_id('login-button')
login_Button.click()
time.sleep(25)


      drop_user_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/header/div[4]/button/span[2]')
        time.sleep(15)
        drop_user_.click()


        time.sleep(10)


        logout = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/header/div[4]/ul/li[3]')
        time.sleep(15)
        logout.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print('account', choice_name, 'verified')
        print('logged out')
        browser.quit()
        endTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
        print("process started at: ", '\n', startTime)
        print("Process ended at: ", '\n', endTime)
```

...

But If my username or password is incorrect it stops and I get a (NosuchElementException) error , witch is to expect ofcourse because if credentials aren't right chrome won't pass the login page witch means it won't find drop_user.

I got this code:

## code

```
while True:
  startTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
print('\n')
usernamelist =  'example@email.com'
passwordstr2 = 'password'


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.maximize_window()


browser.get('https://accounts.spotify.com/en/login?continue=https:%2F%2Fopen.spotify.com%2F')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 5)
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-username")))
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-password")))
wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-button")))
k = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div[3]/div[1]/div/label/span').click()


# log in chrome 1
username = browser.find_element_by_id('login-username')
choice_name = (random.choice(usernamelist))
username.send_keys(choice_name)
print(choice_name)


password = browser.find_element_by_id('login-password')
password.send_keys(passwordstr2)
time.sleep(5)


login_Button = browser.find_element_by_id('login-button')
login_Button.click()
time.sleep(25)

if browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/p/span'):
   print('account', choice_name, 'not verified')
   browser.quit()

 else 
      drop_user_ = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/header/div[4]/button/span[2]')
        time.sleep(15)
        drop_user_.click()


        time.sleep(10)


        logout = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/header/div[4]/ul/li[3]')
        time.sleep(15)
        logout.click()
        time.sleep(5)
        print('account', choice_name, 'verified')
        print('logged out')
        browser.quit()
        endTime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
        print("process started at: ", '\n', startTime)
        print("Process ended at: ", '\n', endTime)
```

...

to restart the loop if wrong login credentials are use but if my username or password is correct in this case I get a error because it won't find this element :

```
     browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/p/span')
```

(python won't find my if statement and breaks the while True loop)

## My Question:

I want code to continue when login credentials are invalid or valid.

1- I want my valid and invalid credentials to be in a separate .text file. #notepad

(file 1.txt for the accounts I would like to check.)

(File 2.txt for the accounts that are invalid.)

How to I do that ? Answer with Complete code please.

2- I would like to run this script 24/7 on AWS.amazon.com ubuntu server.

Any specual code in my needed for this ?

Any help/answers is/are welcome!!!

Thank you in advance.